# Ayuda sobre Java porfavor

Tags: java

Dada estas dos clases se me pide implementar un metodo el cual retroceda a la Room en la cual me encontraba anteriormente. **No se permite el uso de la clase Stack** solo se pueden hacer modificaciones en alguna de estas dos clases adjuntadas anteriormente. Si porfavor a alguien se le ocurre alguna manera de solucionar este metodo porfavor que me responda. Ademas de estas dos clases adjuntadas hay 4 clases mas las cuales no son necesarias para implementar el metodo pedido . Es para una entrega que tengo que realizar en clase antes del proximo viernes a las 14:25 y es la ultima parte de la entrega.

```html
/**
 *  This class is the main class of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 *  "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  Users 
 *  can walk around some scenery. That's all. It should really be extended 
 *  to make it more interesting!
 * 
 *  To play this game, create an instance of this class and call the "play"
 *  method.
 * 
 *  This main class creates and initialises all the others: it creates all
 *  rooms, creates the parser and starts the game.  It also evaluates and
 *  executes the commands that the parser returns.
 * 
 * @author  Michael KÃ¶lling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */

public class Game 
{
    private Parser parser;
    private Room currentRoom;

    /**
     * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
     */
    public Game() 
    {
        createRooms();
        parser = new Parser();
    }

    /**
     * Create all the rooms and link their exits together.
     */
    private void createRooms()
    {
        Room entrada, sotano, jardin, cocina, habitacion, bano;

        // create the rooms
        entrada = new Room("entrada principal de la casa");
        sotano = new Room("sotano");
        jardin = new Room("jardin con flores");
        cocina = new Room("cocina con muebles muy bonitos");
        habitacion = new Room("habitacion del dueno de la casa");
        bano = new Room("bano para el dueno de la casa");
        // initialise room exits
        // Entrada
        entrada.setExit("north", sotano);
        entrada.setExit("east", cocina);
        entrada.setExit("south", jardin);
        entrada.setExit("west", habitacion);
        entrada.setExit("northWest", bano);
        entrada.addItem("Broche de Escarabajo", 100);
        entrada.addItem("Columna de fuego", 1500);
        //Sotano
        sotano.setExit("south", entrada);
        sotano.addItem("Pistola", 498);
        //Jardin
        jardin.setExit("north", entrada);
        jardin.setExit("northWest", habitacion);
        jardin.addItem("Pluma de oro", 1000);
        jardin.addItem("Microscopio", 4500);
        // Cocina
        cocina.setExit("west", entrada);
        //Habitacion
        habitacion.setExit("north", bano);
        habitacion.setExit("east", entrada);
        habitacion.setExit("southEast", jardin);
        habitacion.addItem("Reloj de bolsillo", 25);
        
        //Baño
        bano.setExit("south", habitacion);
        bano.setExit("southEast", entrada);
        bano.addItem("Espejo de oro", 1500);
        bano.addItem("Horquilla de Jade", 4896);
        bano.addItem("Jabonera de oro", 4320);
        currentRoom = entrada;  // start game outside
    }

    /**
     *  Main play routine.  Loops until end of play.
     */
    public void play() 
    {            
        printWelcome();

        // Enter the main command loop.  Here we repeatedly read commands and
        // execute them until the game is over.

        boolean finished = false;
        while (! finished) {
            Command command = parser.getCommand();
            finished = processCommand(command);
        }
        System.out.println("Gracias por jugar.Hasta la proxima");
    }

    /**
     * Print out the opening message for the player.
     */
    private void printWelcome()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Bienvenido al Cluedo");
        System.out.println("En este fantastico juego va a tener que descubrir donde se encuentar el cadaver");
        System.out.println("Teclea 'help' si necesitas ayuda.");
        System.out.println();
        printLocationInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Given a command, process (that is: execute) the command.
     * @param command The command to be processed.
     * @return true If the command ends the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean processCommand(Command command) 
    {
        boolean wantToQuit = false;

        if(command.isUnknown()) {
            System.out.println("No se lo que quiere decir");
            return false;
        }

        String commandWord = command.getCommandWord();
        if (commandWord.equals("help")) {
            printHelp();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("go")) {
            goRoom(command);
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("look")) {
            look();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("back")) {
            
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("eat")) {
            eat();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("quit")) {
            wantToQuit = quit(command);
        } 

        return wantToQuit;
    }

    // implementations of user commands:

    /**
     * Print out some help information.
     * Here we print some stupid, cryptic message and a list of the 
     * command words.
     */
    private void printHelp() 
    {
        System.out.println("Eres un detective.");
        System.out.println("Tu mision es encontrar en que habitacion de la casa se encuentra el cadaver");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("La lista de comandos es la siguiente: ");
        parser.mostrarComandos();
    }

    /** 
     * Try to go in one direction. If there is an exit, enter
     * the new room, otherwise print an error message.
     */
    private void goRoom(Command command) 
    {
        if(!command.hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
            System.out.println("¿Adonde quieres ir?");
            return;
        }

        String direction = command.getSecondWord();

        // Try to leave current room.
        Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExit(direction);

        if (nextRoom == null) {
            System.out.println("No ha puerta para salir");
        }
        else {
            currentRoom = nextRoom;
            printLocationInfo();
        }
    }
    
    /** 
     * "Quit" was entered. Check the rest of the command to see
     * whether we really quit the game.
     * @return true, if this command quits the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean quit(Command command) 
    {
        if(command.hasSecondWord()) {
            System.out.println("Quit what?");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;  // signal that we want to quit
        }
    }

    private void printLocationInfo() {
        System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    private void look() {
        System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
    }
    
    private void eat() {
        System.out.println("Acabas de comer y ya no tienes hambre");
    }
    
}
```

```html
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Class Room - a room in an adventure game.
 *
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 *
 * A "Room" represents one location in the scenery of the game.  It is 
 * connected to other rooms via exits.  The exits are labelled north, 
 * east, south, west.  For each direction, the room stores a reference
 * to the neighboring room, or null if there is no exit in that direction.
 * 
 * @author  Michael KÃ¶lling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class Room 
{
    private String description;
    private ArrayList<Item> objetos;
    private HashMap<String , Room> salidas;
    /**
     * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
     * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
     * "an open court yard".
     * @param description The room's description.
     */
    public Room(String description) 
    {
        this.description = description;
        objetos = new ArrayList<>();
        salidas = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Define una salida para la habitacion.
     * @param direction El nombre de la direccion de la salida
     * @param neighbor La habitacion a la que se llega usando esa salida
     */
    public void setExit(String direccion, Room habitacion) {
        salidas.put(direccion, habitacion);
    }

    /**
     * @return The description of the room.
     */
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public Room getExit(String direccion) {
        return salidas.get(direccion);
    }
    

    /**
     * Devuelve la información de las salidas existentes
     * Por ejemplo: "Exits: north east west"
     *
     * @return Una descripción de las salidas existentes.
     */
    public String getExitString() {
        Set<String> nombreDirecciones = salidas.keySet();
        String salidaString = "Salidas: ";
        for(String direccionActual : nombreDirecciones) {
            salidaString += direccionActual + " ";
        }
        return salidaString;
    }

    public String getObjectDescription() {
        String cadenaADevolver = "";
        if(objetos.isEmpty()) {
            cadenaADevolver = "La sala no contiene ningun objeto";
        } else {
            cadenaADevolver = "La sala contiene los siguintes objetos: \n";
            for(Item itemActual : objetos) {
                cadenaADevolver += itemActual.getDescripcion() + " el cual tiene un peso de " + itemActual.getPeso() + "\n";
            }
        }
        return cadenaADevolver;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve un texto con la descripcion larga de la habitacion del tipo:
     *     You are in the 'name of room'
     *     Exits: north west southwest
     * @return Una descripcion de la habitacion incluyendo sus salidas
     */
    public String getLongDescription() {
        String cadenaADevolver = "Te encuentras en " + description + "\n" ;
        cadenaADevolver += getObjectDescription() + "\n";
        cadenaADevolver += getExitString();
        return cadenaADevolver;
    }
    
    public void addItem(String descripcion , int peso) {
        Item objetoAAgregar = new Item (descripcion , peso);
        objetos.add(objetoAAgregar);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿@Bruno , te ha servido la respuesta de @Cadeq? Si es así puedes aceptar la respuesta ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade una nueva variable `Room previousRoom` donde vas almacenando la habitación en la que estabas antes de moverte a la nueva.

En tu metodo `goRoom`, añade la siguiente linea

```
private void goRoom(Command command) 
{
    if(!command.hasSecondWord()) {
        // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
        System.out.println("¿Adonde quieres ir?");
        return;
    }

    String direction = command.getSecondWord();

    // Try to leave current room.
    Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExit(direction);

    if (nextRoom == null) {
        System.out.println("No ha puerta para salir");
    }
    else {
        previousRoom = currentRoom; //AÑADE ESTA LINEA
        currentRoom = nextRoom;
        printLocationInfo();
    }
}
```

Luego cuando ejecutes la acción de retroceder habitación deberás ejecutar las siguiente linea: `currentRoom=previousRoom;`

---

Ahora vamos a suponer el echo de que quieres retroceder varias veces seguidas. Tal y como esta hecho ahora, solo puedes retroceder una habitación. Así que ahora, el objeto `previousRoom`(la llamaremos previousRooms para este caso) sera una lista de `room`

```
public void backRoom()
{
    if(previousRooms.size()>0)//Nos aseguramos de que no estamos en la salida
    {
        currentRoom=previousRooms.get(previousRooms.size()-1);
        previousRooms.delete(previousRooms.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Ademas habremos adaptado previousRoom a tipo lista, y cuando nos desplacemos de habitación, ejecutaremos `previousRooms.add(currentRoom);` antes de cambiar `currentRoom`

---

Por cierto, el titulo de la pregunta tiene que ser mas descriptivo del problema que te pasa. No pongas un "ayuda por favor" por que así de primeras no se sabe que es.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio